# RxJS unsubscribe doesn't send complete notification

Tags: rxjs

I don't know if it's by design, but why when I call unsubscribe on observable, it doesn't send the complete notification? For example:

```
const sub = timer(1000).subscribe({
  complete() {
    // this isn't being called
  }
});

sub.unsubscribe();
```

Comment: To receive notification of unsubscription, you can use the `finalize` operator: https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/finalize

Comment: @cartant the docs say "but will call a specified function when the source terminates on complete or error", so what's the difference between this operator to call unsubscribe?

Comment: The subscriber can choose to explicitly unsubscribe *before* the source completes. In that situation, `finalize` will call its passed callback, but any callback passed to `subscribe` - as the `complete` callback - won't be called, as the source won't have completed. So I guess the docs are wrong - or, at least, not comprehensive. See [this test](https://twitter.com/1StevieKilner/status/1097228842194948096).

Comment: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/4578

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Err ... the link in the above comment is (obviously) incorrect. It's [this test](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/6.4.0/spec/operators/finalize-spec.ts#L43-L52).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because unsubscribe, unsubscribes you from **the event**, which means that I am not interested with the result anymore. In which case you cannot expect to fire complete event.

> Unsubscribe Disposes the resources held by the subscription. May, for
>   instance, cancel an ongoing Observable execution or cancel any other
>   type of work that started when the Subscription was created.